# CypherQL Sum Rows

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a union query:

```
match (a)--(r)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" return count(a)
union all 
match (a)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" return count(a)
```

This returns something like

```
5
8
```

I would like to execute both queries and return the sum. How can i achieve this?

```
13
```

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` is a set operation, so it will not work for this case. Try this,

```
MATCH (a)--(r)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" 
WITH count(a) as c1
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" 
RETURN c1 + count(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of Neo4j 4.x now allows processing of UNION ALL using subqueries.  You may read the document below to find out more features of it.

> Ref: https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/post-union-processing/

For your example;

```
CALL {
match (a)--(r)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" return count(a) as cnts
union all 
match (a)--(b) where a.name contains "Test" return count(a) as cnts
}
WITH sum(cnts) as totalCnts
RETURN totalCnts

RESULT:
╒═══════════╕
│"totalCnts"│
╞═══════════╡
│ 13        │
└───────────┘
```